# How to view files created in linux in Windows and vice versa?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu

I have Windows 7 and Ubunutu 12.04 installed inside Windows. There is some problem with the formats supported by both of the OS. So many files created in Ubuntu cannot be viewed in Windows. Also there is the problem of end-line encodings which was mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/329816/179185).

I am getting a new laptop and wanted to know how can I take care of this problem?

I wanted to shift to linux for programming but cannot give up on Windows just yet so I am planning of having both OS but this time linux not inside Windows. If the files created in either couldn't be viewed in other OS then it will become a really big problem later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Just save your data on the Windows side, on Ubuntu you can simply mount the `ntfs` volume from Windows and work from it locally.  Not ideal as you will still have the encoding/line ending differences.  Most editors can take care of the line ending issue as necessary.
2. Create another partition in a common formatting and work from it (Windows wants either NTFS, exFAT, or FAT32 most commonly, any of which have support in Linux).

I am sure there are more, but those are pretty simple fixes.  In any case, you'd be able to view files in either OS without a problem.  During compilation going back and forth, however, you may run into some intermittent issues - but that will pretty much happen either way.

I just set all my editors/IDEs/etc. to use the UTF-8 encoding with Unix line endings.  I haven't had much issue yet.  I just do item 1 above for anything shared, but keep the rest in a dropbox folder if I want extra redundancy.

*Note: In the question you linked, they mentioned using option 2 with a multi-OS IDE ( Netbeans, Codeblocks, etc.)*

Answer (score 0):

A linux server called Samba is used to share the files from windows to linux and vice versa.

To set up this server, you can view this youtube link : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTujwRSsIBw

For veiwing linux files in windows, you can install a Linux reader which is a free windows application that allows to access files in the read only mode.

For Windows 98 or later, you can download Linux  reader for free.

This link shows you how you can access Windows file in Linux. Step by step process is shown here making it easy to understand and apply : 
http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Windows-Files-in-Linux

Answer (score 0):

Linux can mount NTFS partitions.

Windows can mout ext2, 3, or 4 partitions if you use [Ext2IFS](http://www.fs-driver.org/).

If you want to access any other partition type such as btrfs under Windows, you need to have a VM running Linux, have the partition mounted in the VM, and expose it over a virtual network using Samba.

You could create a data-sharing partition accessible under both systems, and format it FAT32 or NTFS.

If you are going to encrypt your data, and want an encrypted partition accessible to both OSes, use Truecrypt, which is available for both Windows and Linux.

As far as file types and formats, it really depends on the type of file.  [gVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php), for plain text files, seems to handle the line-ending issue on both Windows and Linux pretty seamlessly, i.e. I open the file and it seems to know what to do.  With other programs such as office software you want to confine yourself to using a format that both Windows and whatever software on Linux you are using can read.